# TestCase issue in mocking

Tags: unit-testing, mockito

As i just started Mockito, I have below method that i want to test. In my YouTubeChannelImporter.java file there are both methods : **readJsonFromUrl(String url) and  readAll(rd)**

```
public JSONObject readJsonFromUrl(String url) throws IOException,
            JSONException {
        InputStream is = new URL(url).openStream();
        try {
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,
                    Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
            String jsonText = readAll(rd);
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonText);
            return json;
        } finally {
            is.close();
        }
    }
```

I started with some rough idea.Below is the sample test case.

```
 @Test
    public void readJsonFromUrl() throws IOException, JSONException {
       String urlTest="http://google.com/api";
       YouTubeChannelImporter mockYoutube = mock(YouTubeChannelImporter.class);
       YouTubeChannelImporter tubeChannelImporter =new YouTubeChannelImporter();
     //  URL url=new URL(urlTest);
     //  InputStream inputStream = mock(InputStream.class);
    //   when(url.openStream()).thenReturn(inputStream);
       BufferedReader rd=mock(BufferedReader.class);
       when(mockYoutube.readAll(rd)).thenReturn("{\"kind\":\"you\"}");
       String jsonText="{\"kind\":\"you\"}";
       JSONObject object=new JSONObject(jsonText);
       assertEquals("{\"kind\":\"you\"}",tubeChannelImporter.readJsonFromUrl(urlTest).toString());
    }
```

My issue is when i will test the function readJsonFromUrl(String url) then readAll(rd) should not execute. Rather mock should be in action here. I am aware this issue is because *tubeChannelImporter.readJsonFromUrl(urlTest).toString()* . Looking for any other way to achieve my goal.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mocking one instance of your class, and then executing another - as you noticed, this does not achieve the intended result.

I think the easiest way of testing your method is with `spy`ing ("partial mocking"). With this technique, you'll have an actual instance of your class with only a single method, `readAll` mocked out:

```
@Test
public void readJsonFromUrl() throws IOException, JSONException {
   // Set up the spied instance:
   YouTubeChannelImporter tubeChannelImporter = spy(new YouTubeChannelImporter());
   doReturn("{\"kind\":\"you\"}").when(tubeChannelImporter).readAll(any(Reader.class));

   // Test the execution
   String urlTest="http://google.com/api";
   String jsonText="{\"kind\":\"you\"}";
   JSONObject object=new JSONObject(jsonText);
   assertEquals("{\"kind\":\"you\"}",tubeChannelImporter.readJsonFromUrl(urlTest).toString());
}
```

Comment: Hi I am getting NPE at         when(tubeChannelImporter.readAll(any(Reader.class))).thenReturn("{\"kind\":\"you\"}");
. Also readAll accept Reader as argument where its defined.

Comment: @user3645799 copy-paste bug :-( Should have been done with `doReturn` since it's a spied object, not a mock - see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, for a test like this where you have to read a file and there's not much else going on, I would read an actual file rather than mock out a BufferedReader. Then you just have to *Assert* on the `JSONObject` output from the call to `readJsonFromUrl()`.

Your problems stem from trying to test against the `private` method `readAll()`. Try to test only your `public` methods in your tests (e.g. `readJsonFromUrl()`) and you'll find you have to jump through less hoops in your test code.

If your class already implements an `Interface`, then [just write tests against the Interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface).

If you find that you have a lot of private methods, perhaps your class is [responsible for doing too much work](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), so factor methods out into their own class(es). Then you can test them in isolation.

If you have a maven project, the place to put your test files, to read from, is in `/src/test/resources`